# JavaScript variables hoisting in nodejs/async

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, async.js

In the next example I **don't have access to variable "locals"** inside the functions "fetcher", "parser" and "saveToDb".

```
var parser = require('parser.js');
var fetcher = require('fetcher.js');
var saveToDb = require('models/model.js');
var async = require('async');


function task() {
    var locals = []    //<-- declared here
    async.series([
        fetcher,    //<--  can not access "locals"
        parser,     //<--  can not access "locals"
        saveToDb    //<--  can not access "locals"
    ],
            function (err) {
                if (err) return callback(err);
                callback(null);
    });
}
```

In the next example **"local"s is accessible**. I just copyed the functions declarations from the requested modules, and pasted them straight inside "async.series".

```
var async = require('async');

function task() {
    var locals = []    //<-- declared here
    async.series([
        function(callback) {// <-- can access "locals"},  
        function(callback) {// <-- can access "locals"},
        function(callback) {// <-- can access "locals"}
    ],
            function (err) {
                if (err) return callback(err);
                callback(null);
    });
}
```

While this works - I do want to keep my code modular. 
How can I fix that ? **Or - what I forgot here about the fundamentals of JavaScript** ?

Thanks.

Comment: It could be said that you are forgetting one thing: That your code won't be very modular if it *could* access more or less random variables (in this case the `locals` variable) defined elsewhere. Making something modular usually takes more than just spreading things around files, it's also about making relationships between different parts of your code explicit, for example by passing all data a function needs as arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, the callbacks live in another scope so can't access `locals`.

You could create partial functions that get the `locals` variable passed as first argument, but that would require you to rewrite your callbacks.

```
// creating a partial
async.series([
  fetcher.bind(fetcher, locals),
  parser.bind(parser, locals),
  saveToDb.bind(saveToDb, locals)
], ...)

// new function signatures
function fetcher (locals, callback) { ... }
function parser  (locals, callback) { ... }
function saveToDb(locals, callback) { ... }
```

Comment: Why the bind? I guess that because I don't use "this" inside my specific callback - it does not really matter - but I do want to understand why you added the bind. Thanks robert.

Comment: `bind` serves two purposes: determine what `this` is in the function, but also to create partial functions which have pre-specified arguments 'attached' to them (see [the MDN explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partial_Functions), and [here a simple gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/5729837) to demonstrate the principle).

Comment: I think I got this part right now, but will that work even if "async.series" takes no arguments except "callback" ?

Comment: Sure :) I updated [my gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/5729837) to show how you can use it with `async`.

Comment: I think the `fetcher.bind(fetcher, locals)` could better be `fetcher.bind(undefined, locals)` Specifying the original function as value for `this` looks weird to me.

Comment: @MerynStol sure, or `null` or whatever :) I have the habit of passing the original object to `bind` usually, although in this case it doesn't make much sense I have to admit (**edit**: okay, here's a convoluted [gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/5730649) to show what you might be missing ;)

Comment: @robertklep Seems I'm not missing out on much, thankfully. ;)

Comment: Robert - it seems to almost work. Every function now has access to the value of "locals" - but only to the first value - it's not "two way binding" - am I wrong ?

Comment: off-course, the explicit arguments produce a new inner scope. I can't change "locals" across functions this way...

Comment: @Daniel it sounds like you want to use `locals` to share/pass some state between the different callbacks. If so, you should consider using [`async.waterfall`](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfalltasks-callback) instead of `async.series`.

Comment: (although [this gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/5732354) seems to suggest that you could pass data around with the method I proposed)

Comment: @robertklep, yeah just saw that and will use that. but I still wonder for my understanding - if there's a way without waterfall, maybe using a closure and self invoked functions...

Comment: @robertklep, I saw the gist, there's no write access to the outer locals from inside the functions when the arguments are passed explicitly(I mean it's read only)... as far as I can see and checked again.

Comment: @Daniel oh, that's absolutely right, it's not a magic trick to break out of the current scope :)

Answer (score 2):

You can have the 3 mentionned functions defined like this :

```
function fetcher(locals) {
  return function _fetcher(callback) {
    // this function body will have access to locals
  }
}
```

and rewrite your code as:

```
function task() {
    var locals = []    //<-- declared here
    async.series([
        fetcher(locals),    //<--  can now access "locals"
        parser(locals),     //<--  can now access "locals"
        saveToDb(locals)    //<--  can now access "locals"
    ],
            function (err) {
                if (err) return callback(err);
                callback(null);
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if "async.series" takes arguments except "callback", I'll check that. Thanks matehat.

Answer (score 0):

IF i understand your problem correctly this is a javascript 101 question.

fetcher can be a factory that creates a concrete fetcher.

```
var fetcher = function(locals){
 locals=locals||[] // optional , assign a default , whatever ...
 return function(){
   //do some operation with locals.
   doSomething(locals);
 }
}
```

then in your script

```
 async.series([
        fetcher(locals),    //<--  will return the callback to use
        parser(locals),     //<--  will return the callback to use
        saveToDb(locals)    //<--  will return the callback to use
    ],
```

i believe it is a kind of currying.

Comment: "async.series" takes no arguments except "callback" (I think), and also "locals" is my main "data" - I cannot delete it each time. Thanks mpm.